# Unable to send alt key with xdotool

Tags: xdotool

I am trying the following command:

```
xdotool key --clearmodifiers --delay 500 alt+f
```

and the result is the following error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  132 (XTEST)
Minor opcode of failed request:  2 (X_XTestFakeInput)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  18
Current serial number in output stream:  19
```

I tried without the `--clearmodifiers` and `--delay` but still the same error.

My system is Arch Linux and i3 window manager.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also running the same setup as my primary OS (arch + i3). I tried downloading *xdotool* and running the same command. It works both with and without the two options.

I'd try the following if it wasn't working (unless you have already):

```
1> Reinstall *xdotool*, update, and reboot.
2> Although it worked, my mod key is set to the *win* key so I'm not sure if that somehow causes issues with 
a programmable keypress (you wouldn't think so). Try temporarily changing the modifier to the *win* key in your config and reinstall xdotool.
3> I would also try reinstalling its dependencies (namely libxtst and libxinerama)
4> If all of the above fails, I'd try the *xdotool-gui* package from the AUR instead and see if that fixes anything.
```

One question: Just to verify, is that error *always* persistent, or is it only in that one case of *alt+f*?

Regards :)